# Is it possible to access Apache virtual hosts over a local network without editing client computers hosts files?

Tags: apache, sql-server-2008-r2, virtualhost, windows-sbs

I have several websites set up on my local XAMPP, and have recently setup virtual hosts so that they can be accessed from my machine using dev.website1.com, dev.website2.com etc.

To achieve this I had to edit my hosts file C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts to ensure the name resolves to the correct IP address.

I would now like to make the sites accessible from other computers on the local network, but editing the hosts file for each machine manually seems to be a bad way of doing it, as it would quickly become unmanageable with several machines/addresses to keep on top of.

My question is:  Is it possible to add a DNS record or similar to the domain server of our local network (SBS 2008-R2), so that machines on our network can access my websites without having to edit the hosts file on each machine?

Apologies if this is a noob question - I have tried to RTFM, but I am not a network specialist and can't really even be sure if what I'm reading is relevant to my problem, so I really need some help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research I eventually found out how to achieve what I want.  I created a **new forward lookup zone** with the address dev.testsite.com, and then created a **blank A record** and set it to the IP address I wanted it to forward to.  Anyone on my network can now type dev.testsite.com to see the local apache server, or www.testsite.com to see the live version.

I'm sure there are also other ways of achieving this, but as far as I know this is the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a made-up hostname, it either has to be in your hosts file or in DNS. It's obviously possible to add new subdomains or aliases (CNAME) that point to your existing IP/host to any DNS server -- it's would seem to be a routine operation for your DNS administrator.

Comment: Yes - this is exactly what I wanted to do...  I was asking how to do it!! :)